# Strange-looking type in client side when using generics in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm rather new to WCF, and have created created a service with the following two methods:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDB
{
    [OperationContract]
    DbResponse<Student> AddStudent(string pnr, string firstName, string lastName, string userName, string email, string cls);

    [OperationContract]
    DbResponse<List<Student>> FindStudent(string searchString);
}
```

The DbResponse is a generic class:

```
[DataContract]
public class DbResponse<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public DbStatus Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

where DbStatus is an enum:

```
[DataContract]
public enum DbStatus
{ 
    [EnumMember]
    Ok,
    [EnumMember]
    Warning,
    [EnumMember]
    Failed
};
```

This works fine, except that on the client side, since adding the generic property to DbResponse, I can no longer use the following:

```
string filter = "Foo";
DBClient dbc = new DBClient();
WebInterface.Services.DbResponse response = dbc.FindStudent(filter);
```

Instead, according to Intellisense, I have to use the strange-looking (and ugly) type:

```
WebInterface.Services.DbResponseOfArrayOfStudentL1_PcKk2u response = dbc.FindStudent(filter);
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could shed some light over why this happens and if (and how) I can use a "cleaner" type name.

Comment: WCF's data exchange over the wire is done by means of **XML serialization** and XML schema - and that doesn't really support generics. That's why you get these "mangled" names. For WCF data transfer, you should be using only concrete, non-generic types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found out that the hash can be overridden by using the Name property in the DataContract attribute (http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/05/10/wcf-serialization-and-generics.aspx):

```
[DataContract(Name = "DbResponse{0}"]
public class DbResponse<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public DbStatus Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

This will still output e.g. DbResponseOfArrayOfStudent, but at least there is no ugly hash, so I guess I will have to live with that.